# RxJs equivalent of promise chain

Tags: angular, rxjs

When chaining API calls with promises I do this:

```
this.http.get('/api/hello').toPromise().then(res => {
  return this.http.get('/api/there/' + res.id).toPromise()
}).then(res => {
  console.log('res from 2nd call', res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('err', err)
})
```

How do you chain API calls like this using Observables, when the 2nd response needs data from the 1st response before it can be made?

TIA

Comment: switchMap or mergeMap

Comment: Remember that `mergeMap` is the new name of `flatMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `flatMap` Please visit this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-rxjx-stuff. I have created this project for testing RxJS.

You can see the below function.

```
  test__flatMap() {
    const post$ = this.getPosts();
    const users$ = this.getUsers();
    const users2$ = this.getUsers();

    post$.pipe(
      flatMap(data => {
        console.log('data 1 >>> ', data);
        return users$;
      }),
      flatMap(data => {
        console.log('data 2 >>> ', data);
        return post$;
      }),
    ).subscribe(data => { console.log(`In the end >>> `, data); });
  }
```

Comment: Remember that mergeMap is the new name of flatMap - thanks @Picci

Answer (score 1):

`mergeMap` is an option:

```
this.http.get(/api/hello')
    .pipe(mergeMap((s) => {
        return s;
    }),
    mergeMap((res) =>{
      const url ='/api/there/' + res.id;
      return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((res) =>   {
            return res;
        }));
    }))
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);//final response
    }, 
    undefined,
    () => console.log('complete'));
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwsltm

Comment: Remember that mergeMap is the new name of flatMap - thanks @Picci

Comment: @danday74 Thanks replaced with `mergeMap` and added a stacblitz demo.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switchMap` to execute another http.get after the first pushes data. `switchMap` has the advantage that it cancels all pending inner requests when the parent pushes new data.

```
const request$ = this.http.get('pathto/api').pipe(
  switchMap((res) => {
    return this.http.get(`another/api/${res.id}`)
  })
);

request$.subscribe(innerRequestData => {
  // do whatever you want
});
```

Don't forget to subscribe, since otherwise it is a *cold* observable.